# php rename failure

Tags: php, rename

I have some problems with PHP Rename .

```
 $rm = rename($path.$package."/",$path.$get["theme_name"]."/");
                     if ($rm == FALSE)
                     {
                        return "RENAME_FAILURE";
                     }
```

here i got a error

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

```
Message: rename(/home/pr/public_html/developer/public_themes/arkGT/,/home/pr/public_html/developer/public_themes/new_roller/) [function.rename]: Directory not empty

Filename: models/pagemodel.php

Line Number: 218
```

i checked the cpanel,everything is ok,the folder is renamed to `new_roller`...

then what is the problem with my code ?

Thank you.

Comment: You are being warned that you directory isn't empty. The code is still functioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
 $rm = rename("./public_themes/arkGT/","./public_themes/new_roller/");
    if ($rm == FALSE)
    {
     return "RENAME_FAILURE";
    }
    else
    {
    return "success";
    }
```

Your code is correct .

Comment: try to avoid a long path.I think `developer` is your root directory?