# php rename folders with files into

Tags: php, directory, rename

I am trying to write a script in PHP to reset my ids in a database. But I must to rename the directories in my tables to which have same ids.

So I try to use the rename function but I failed.

I always have "No such file or directory". I try the absolute or relative path, to change chmod, to use a sleep before and yes my folders are existing.

So I would know why this doesn't work :

```
rename('/uploads/photos/'.$old_id.'/', '/uploads/photos/'.$new_id.'/');
```

And my folders have some files into.

Comment: `reset my ids in a database` - not usually a good idea. Primary keys should be abstracted from the data they refer to - they should have relevance to the data itself. Please explain why you feel you need to do this. But to answer the actual question, try `rename('uploads/photos/'.$old_id, 'uploads/photos/'.$new_id);` with no leading/trailing slashes, unless you really do have a directory in the file system root called `/uploads` (which I doubt)...

Comment: have you tried it without the trailing slash?

Comment: Really I think that the OS is searching "uploads" in the root folder. Try using the complete path, for example: /var/www/uploads/photos/....

Comment: I need to reset the ids because I had 118k results and now only 200, its to have clean ids and urls. I'll try whithout the leading slashes and I tried whithout the trailing and it was the same.

Comment: As already written by DaveRandom, id values should NEVER be modified. An id is a **permanent** reference to a record.

Comment: Ah ah without the leading and trailing slashes I have this message : "Directory not empty". So how I can fix that ?

Comment: Hi, try to check these answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9043193/php-rename-failure

Answer (score 4):

just use linux command in php:

```
exec("mv $oldname $newname");
```

Comment: Sometimes it's the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

1- Fix permission of parent directory. ( `photos` ) It must be writable by your php user.

2- Make sure your path is ok `/uploads/photos/...` (Your first slash means it's an absolute path from root directory)